# Partial Match If Statement Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I am trying to find a partial string match in a certain column of my dataframe (Title). Ideally i would like pandas to create a true false column if the partial string match is true and false if the string match is false. I would like to you a def function in order to do this to create an if/else statement as my data set is quite large.

If the column 'Title' has the word 'dog' in it, then put a true in that row in my new column 'Match'.

```
Old Dataframe example:

Title          Author Name  
Dogs R Us      John Smith
Pigs can Fly   Henry White
Dog Games      Adam James         


New Dataframe example:
Title          Author Name      Match  
Dogs R Us      John Smith       True
Pigs can Fly   Henry White      False
Dog Games      Adam James       True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `str.contains`

```
In [832]: df.Title.str.contains('Dog')
Out[832]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: Title, dtype: bool

In [833]: df['Match'] = df.Title.str.contains('Dog')

In [834]: df
Out[834]:
          Title  Author Name  Match
0     Dogs R Us   John Smith   True
1  Pigs can Fly  Henry White  False
2     Dog Games   Adam James   True
```

Comment: @ John Galt Thank you very much for your quick and great responses. What if I wanted to match multiple strings. For example, i wanted to find all titles that have the word Dogs as well as all tiles with Cats in it as well as all titles with Pigs in it. Can i do this in one line of code ?

Comment: Instead of 'Dog' you could use separator like 'Dog|Cat'

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`pandas.Series.str.contains`.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

```
>>> df
          title
0     dogs r us
1  pigs can fly
2     dog games

>>> df['Match'] = df.title.str.contains('dog')

>>> df
          title  Match
0     dogs r us   True
1  pigs can fly  False
2     dog games   True
```

If you want the check to be case insensitive, you can use a `re.IGNORECASE` flag.

```
>>> df['Match'] = df.title.str.contains('dog', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Since this is using `re.search`, you can check for multiple strings with a regular regex way, something like

```
>>> df['Match'] = df.title.str.contains('dog|cats', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: for a case independent `contains` do `df.title.str.contains('dog', case=False)`

Comment: @bunji Flag works too I believe. (see my edited answer)

Comment: @Mitch please see my comment below for some addtional help. Thanks

Comment: @spacedinosaur10 I updated my answer. Please consider asking another question if you run into further issues instead of pushing this one on.